# Remove charts drawn the first time with progressbar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

On page load, I have a function like this :

```
function getResults(id) {
    var url = "/users/" + id;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var vid = data.calculated.length - 1;
            getResults(vid);
            data.survey.forEach(function (surveyData) {
                    $('#surveys').append(
                         new Option(
                             new Date(surveyData.submittedDate).toDateString(), 
                                 surveyData.id));
                }
            })
    });
}
```

The getResults function does this :

```
function getResults(vid) {
    var url = "/survey/" + vid;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var results = data;
        AnimateCircle("circle1", results.surveyResults["first"], "A");
        AnimateCircle("circle1", results.surveyDataResults["second"], "B");
    })
}
```

Now, after the dropdown with surveys has been filled out with values, when the option is changed I call  getResults again where vid is different :

```
$('#data').change(function () {
    var vid = $('#data').val();
    getResults(vid);
});
```

The problem is that the charts called with AnimateCircle() function,gets called every time I choose a different option in the dropdown, and instead I want the old charts to be removed, and new ones with the new values on top of them.

I tried by calling circle.destroy(); on the onChange function, but it only destroys the last AnimateCircle called.
How do I make a loop to destroy all of them ? Or is there a better way that when I call the function for the second time, the first charts get updated ?

AnimateCircle function :

```
function AnimateCircle(container_id, animatePercentage, type) {
    var startColor = '#FC5B3F';
    var endColor = '#F18F01';
    var element = document.getElementById(container_id);
    circle = new ProgressBar.Circle(element, {
        color: startColor,
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 3,
        duration: 1400,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        text: {
            value: "<h4>" + type + "</h4>" + "<h4>" + (animatePercentage) * 10 + "</h1>",
            className: 'progressbar__label'
        },
        step: function (state, circle) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        }
    });
    circle.animate(animatePercentage, {
        from: {
            color: startColor
        },
        to: {
            color: endColor
        }
    });
    circle.path.style.strokeLinecap = 'round';
}
```

Uses progressbar.js

Comment: what exactly does `AnimateCircle` do?

Comment: I added the function. Thank you.
It draws a circle chart using progressbar.js

Comment: you could try to return a reference to `circle` in your `AnimateCircle` function and then destroy each instance you previously created when you call `getResults`

Comment: I tried making circle a global variable, and then destroy it. But I'm not sure how to destroy all of them. How do you suggest doing that ? have a return circle in the end of the function, and then how to destroy each instance ?
I'm sorry if it's simple, i'm new at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't really test this code, so I'm not 100% sure it will work, but I was thinking of something like:

```
var first, second;

function getResults(vid) {
    var url = "/survey/" + vid;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var results = data;
        if (first) first.destroy();
        if (second) second.destroy();

        first = AnimateCircle("circle1", results.surveyResults["first"], "A");
        second = AnimateCircle("circle1", results.surveyDataResults["second"], "B");
    })
}
```

and as for your AnimateCircle:

```
function AnimateCircle(...) {
  ...
  var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle(element, ...);

  // do your stuff

  return circle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! A lifesaver truly! Exactly what I was looking for!
Thank you!!